# Unable to assign property CFrame. CoordinateFrame expected, got Vector3

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

So, I was trying to make that it scans everything in user's body and if it's called humanoidRootPart, it will save the the position. Instead of it i got the error 'Unable to assign property CFrame. CoordinateFrame expected, got Vector3'

```
for i,v in pairs(plrChar:GetChildren()) do
            if v.Name == "HumanoidRootPart" then
                game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').savedPos.Value = Vector3.new(v.Position)
            end
end
```

Comment: Well, were did you define `savedPos`? Apparently it's not a Vector3 :)

Comment: i did that already before, it gave me Unable to assign property Value. Vector3 expected, got CFrame

Comment: I don't think your error is coming from this code. You aren't assigning anything to the CFrame property in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If savedpos is a CFrame Value, instead of just assigning it's Value to "Vector3.new(v.Position)" (which is already redundant as "Position" is already a Vector3) you should use "CFrame.new(v.Position)"